# Why does my textbox round up an amount to 10 decimal places?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a table that includes a customer's balance/interest accrued amount. I have created a button that, when pressed, will search for a specific customers balance and fill a text box with it. However, it seems that if that balance is longer than 10 decimal places, the amount is rounded to 10 decimal places inside the text box. Why is this and can this can be changed?

```csharp
using (SQLiteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    try
    {
        cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT allowance FROM customer WHERE custid = @custid";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("custid", Global.selectedCust);
        SQLiteDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (read.Read())
        {
            txt_amount.Text = read["allowance"].ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

That's the code I'm using to read the table and retrieve the balance amount.

I couldn't see any settings in the textbox properties that would turn this off. Will I have to round up the balance amounts so there are fewer decimal places?

Comment: What is the details of the text box code?  There could be a max length on there or is the box short so you cant see all the digits but they may be there still if you click it and scroll to the right?

Comment: Could you double check the value in the database?

Comment: number.ToString("0.000###") use this to round up as much as you want using string formatting.

Comment: What is the type of `allowance` in the database?  What underlying type does `read["allowance"]` return (decimal, double or float)?  The function will return an `object`, but that will be the _boxed_ version of some underlying value type.

Comment: Probably a problem with syntax highlighting on Stack Overflow: Why isn't "`catch`" in the same colour as "`try`"? Is it confused by "`@custid`" (on the fifth line)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually .ToString() keeps 15 digits of precision by default. You can extend it up to 17 with .ToString("G17").

Comment: What datatype is actually used here? Why aren't the last two digits bogus (not rhetorical questions)?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the number of decimal points to be shown using the following:

```
number.ToString("0.000##")
```